# How to add multiple box shadows using Tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css

I want to give 2 box shadows using tailwind css

CSS:

```
button{
     box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px var(--primary-500), inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
      }
```

This is what I'm able to achieve using tailwind css:

```
<button class="shadow-[inset_0_0_0_1px_var(--primary-500)]"> Hello World! </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shadow classes that come with Tailwind use multiple shadows, e.g. the class `shadow` translates to `box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 1px 2px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);` in CSS.

If you need to add additional shadows or customise these values, you can do so by editing `theme.boxShadow` or `theme.extend.boxShadow` in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

If a `DEFAULT` shadow is provided, it will be used for the non-suffixed shadow utility. Any other keys will be used as suffixes, for example the key `'2'` will create a corresponding `shadow-2` utility.

Comment: Is there a way to customize the tailwind config so DEFAULT or lg for example have two custom shadows?

Comment: Nevermind found it here: https://design2tailwind.com/blog/tailwindcss-box-shadows-how-to/

Answer (score 7):

To use multiple box-shadows you can use comma separated box-shadow's values inside square brackets.

```html
<button
 class="shadow-[inset_0_0_0_1px_var(--primary-500),inset_0px_0px_0px_2px_red]">
 Hello World!
</button>
```

Comment: Aga's example is correct for using arbitrary values. Luke's info is still relevant if you want to add custom classes or modify Tailwind defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Tailwind Extended Shadows plugin](https://github.com/kaelansmith/tailwind-extended-shadows) to auto-generate box-shadow layers based on the "base" shadow, among other things like controlling shadow offset and spread... all with utility classes!

For example:

```html
<div class="shadow-sm shadow-y-[4px] shadows-4 shadows-scale-2">...</div>
```

In the example, the default `shadow-sm` class is applied, but its y-offset is adjusted to `4px` (via `shadow-y-[4px]`), and 3 additional shadow layers are auto-generated (thanks to the `shadows-4` class.. you can choose between 2-8 layers). The shadow layers' offset/blur values are also scaled up using the multiplier specified by the `shadows-scale-*` class; you can even apply an easing function to the scaling math via `shadows-ease-{in|out}`.

Here's a demo playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Wk1G8cIkr3

Note: I authored this plugin -- very open to feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly your issue but if someone is facing this issue where they want to apply multiple box shadows using Tailwind utilities inside `class` attribute and where some of the values are CSS variables like `var(--box-shadow-top)`. Tailwind will be confused and will think that the arbitrary values are for shadow color!

You can try this:

```
shadow-[shadow:var(--box-shadow-top),inset_0_0_0_1px_var(--orange-9),var(--box-shadow-bottom)]
```

Please note `shadow:` inside the `[...]` to avoid ambiguity between box shadow and shadow color. Refer to [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#resolving-ambiguities) for how to resolve issues like this.